# Should an iterator be defined as another class?

Tags: python, iterator

Suppose we have this class definition:

```
class Series(object):
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.current = low
        self.high = high

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current > self.high:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current += 1
            return self.current - 1
```

In my opinion, this implementation is logically wrong. Indeed, we cannot have two independant iterators of this class:

```
s = Series(1,10)
it1 = iter(s)
print(next(it1))     # prints 1

it2 = iter(s)
print(next(it2))     # should print 1 but it prints 2
```

So my question is: Is it necessary to define another class for `series_iterator` in order to implement it well, or there is a way to implement a iterable and its iterator as the same class?

Comment: It is better if use a different type, so that the state of the iterator is decoupled.  Consider list as a good example to follow here, every call to `iter(some_list)` will return separate instances of a `list_iterator` type, which can be consumed at different rates. They will both still reference the original list's state for yielding the values (and the list can be mutated during iteration), but they will each maintain their own state for the iteration index and whether they're exhausted or not.

Comment: An easy way to have your cake and eat it, too, is to make `__iter__` a generator.

Comment: @wim in contrast to the accepted answer you would argue that an iterator shouldn't be implemented on the class itself but in a custom class to decouple its state, correct?

Comment: @KenJiiii Yes, that's right, but the accepted answer is actually okay - it is returning a generator instance, not returning the instance of `Series`. Multiple iterators could be taken from the same `Series` instance without problems: each iterator would retain its own state using the local scope of the generator frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is: Is it necessary to define another class for `series_iterator` in order to implement it well?

No:

```
class Series:
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.low = low
        self.high = high

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.low
        while current <= self.high:
            current += 1
            yield current - 1
```

By making `__iter__` a generator, you don't have to define a new class for proper iterable behaviour. This won't *always* solve everything, since it's not as powerful as a seperate class, but in a large amount of cases, it's more than enough — and clearer.

Note that you don't have to implement `__next__` now — that is already defined for you on the generator type.